# Why is the controls getting bigger when using pages in WPF? And how do I fix it?

Tags: c#, wpf

I am practicing some new wpf stuff and currently reading a book with exercises in them. The exercises uses pages in the wpf application, But a problem occurs when I start the program, the pages doesn't look the way I made them in Visual Studio. For example, I create a TextBox inside a Grid with one cell so it takes up the whole screen in the preview window inside VS. But when the application starts it's as if the whole TextBox got bigger and can't fit the screen so you have to resize the window to see the whole borderof the TextBox. If anyone understands it and knows how to fix it it would be very greatful.

Comment: This could be useful for you; https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/1e050f/grid-layout-in-wpf/#:~:text=A%20Grid%20is%20a%20very,container%20inside%20the%20window%20element.

Answer (score 1):

I had removed the d:Design from both widh and height. I put them back and now it's working